# Specific user paths on poedit files

Tags: versioning, poedit

Do you think its a bad habit - or a problem - to include the custom user machine path on the poedit translation paths?

`"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: /myProjectName/Backend/module/Core\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-1: /Users/someUser/Documents/Projects/clipp/Backend/module/Core\n"`

The first path is the global one, but as developers enter in the projects entries like the second path starts to appearing. This entries are versioned too and ends to populate the base with many alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s a bad thing to do. I consider it a design failure that Poedit even *allows* this and 1.8 is going to fix this part of its UI.

You are seeing yourself why it’s bad: it makes the PO file not portable to other machines. You should use a *relative* path (from the location of the PO file to `…/module/Core` instead.

See https://github.com/vslavik/poedit/wiki/PO-Extensions for description of the `X-Poedit-*` headers.